# how do I change the input dimensions for fully convolutional tflite model?

Tags: android, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, dimensions

I have a `tflite` model file for my android application that is created with input dimensions `[None,1280,720,3]` for RGB input. I would like to use the same model if I also get FHD size image inputs `[ None, 1920, 1080, 3]`.

Is there a way to change the input dimensions during inference time?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend training the above model with the new input dimension if you really want to get a better result in terms of accuracy by doing more computations. If not feasible, you can resize the given FHD-sized RGB inputs to the HD sized RGB data as a preprocessing step before invoking the model and then, you can provide the resized data to the same model.

Comment: I can resize the inputs, but I would rather not do that since its a pixel2pixel model for style transfer. I was looking for a way to just change the size of the input dimensions, given the tflite model